# Expression engine channel entries keep next to each other

Tags: expressionengine, channel

I am trying to keep my channel entries next to each other.

Usual way to print channel entries:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="10"}
                <h2>{title}</h2>

               {news_body}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

So the news print under each other like this:

```
  Title 1 Blah Blah

  ashdjsdsd asdsda ada
  adasdasda asdsda adad

  Title 2 Blah Blah

  jsaudwi llasdju alsl
  asdasdas
```

I want to print two news articles next to each other like this:

```
  Title 1 Blah Blah            Title 2 Blah Blah

  jsaudwi llasdju alsl        ashdjsdsd asdsda ada
  asdasdas                    adasdasda asdsda adad
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[imjared's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11183515/174299) is good from an HTML/CSS perspective, but since this is tagged as an ExpressionEngine question, here's how to solve this via EE syntax, with self-explanatory HTML.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="10"}
<div class="{switch="float-left|float-right"}">
    <h2>{title}</h2>
    {news_body}
</div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. For some reason it did not work.  The code is elegant.  I tried to plug in the code about an hour.  I am a newbe to EE.  If you can could you kindly check the code again?  Thank you very much again.

Comment: Is the HTML being output correctly (i.e., odd-numbered divs are classed "float-left" and even-numbered divs are classed "float-right")? You'd obviously need to add CSS rules for "float-left" and "float-right" in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much for checking my issue and helping me. Yes, it works.  Great beautiful code. I adapted your code. I do not know the point system in Stack Over flow.  I will try to give highest points.  Thank you very much again

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more of a html/css question than ExpressionEngine and there are a couple of ways you could do this:

- http://jsfiddle.net/xJyqs/
- http://jsfiddle.net/xJyqs/2/ (if you're not concerned about old browser support)

The way I'd do it is something like the following--

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="10"}
<div class="entry">
<h2>{title}</h2>
{news_body}
</div><!--/.entry-->
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  It works. This is a great help.  I tried to solve this issue about 2 hrs. Thanks again